# How To Create Associative Array In EcmaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to create an associative array within the constructor. But  the below code throws error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'num' of undefined

```
class Validate{

    constructor(){

        this.name['num'] = ['one','two'];
    }
    display() {




        console.log(this.name['num']);
    }



}
```

Comment: You first have to define `this.name` as _something_.

Comment: @Xufox Can u Pls write the code

Comment: JavaScript does not have associative arrays, so you can't create one.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the problem is that it cannot set property `num` of undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will initialize name and after that use property of your object . In this case  name is not defined and you try to set property of undefined.

```js
class Validator
{
  
  constructor(){

        this.name = {num :['one','two']} ;
        
    }
    display() {


       

        console.log(this.name['num']);
    } 
}
 var validator = new Validator();
validator.display();
```

Comment: For questions like these, the _explanation_ of the problem is far more important than a solution that is “ready to copy”.

Comment: because name is not defined and you try to set property of undefined.

Comment: This is not an associative array, whatever that is. It's an object.

Comment: @ArturHovhannisyan Edit your answer. Don’t put the most important part in the comments.

Comment: @Xufox thank for advice

Comment: @ArturHovhannisyan thank u !!!

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has no associative array, but Object literal can be used as an alternative.
Here, you need to define the object before using it.

```
class Validate{
    constructor(){
        this.name={}//define this.name
        this.name['num'] = ['one','two'];
    }
    display() {
        console.log(this.name['num']);
    }
}
```